# Get a list of all the implementations of an Interface in Android

Tags: java, android, interface

I am working on a project in Android and want to know the Internet Connection State in every Activity and my App has more than 15 activities so, I don't want to implement and initialize my networkstatechanged class and interface in every activity.
So, I have created it's instance in a class that extends Application in which I create a object of my interface.

My NetworkStateChanged Class:

NetworkConnected.java

```
package time.real.identify.location.tracker.gps.saksham.com.emptrackerhost;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

interface NetworkListener {
    void isConnected();
    void isDisconnected();
}


public class NetworkConnected {

    private List<NetworkListener> listeners = new ArrayList<NetworkListener>();
    private boolean isConnected = false;
    private boolean wasConnected = false;

    NetworkConnected() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                isConnected = isOnline();
                wasConnected = isConnected;
                notifySomethingHappened();
                while(true){
                    isConnected = isOnline();
                    if(wasConnected != isConnected){
                        wasConnected = isConnected;
                        notifySomethingHappened();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
    private boolean isOnline() {
        try {
            int timeoutMs = 3000;
            Socket sock = new Socket();
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);

            sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
            sock.close();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    void addListener(NetworkListener listener) { listeners.add(listener); }
    private void notifySomethingHappened() {
        for (NetworkListener listener : listeners) {
            if(isConnected){
                listener.isConnected();
            }
            else{
                listener.isDisconnected();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

ApplicationClass.java

```
package time.real.identify.location.tracker.gps.saksham.com.emptrackerhost;

import android.app.Application;

public class ApplicationClass extends Application {

    public static boolean isNetworkConnected = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        new NetworkConnected().addListener(new time.real.identify.location.tracker.gps.saksham.com.emptrackerhost.NetworkListener() {
            @Override
            public void isConnected() {
                isNetworkConnected = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void isDisconnected() {
                isNetworkConnected = false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

After this I would just like to implement a interface in every class which would not need to be added as listener or initialized since one object is already running.

I want something like this:-

```
public class LoginPageClass extends Activity implements NetworkListener
{
public void isConnected(){
//Make a Snackbar
}
public void isDisconnected(){
//Make a Snackbar
}
}
```

Note:- I don't want to call object of myNetworkListener Class from ApplicationClass to add listener(this);

I just want to get a list of classes that implement my NetworkConnected Class in order to provide a state change callback to them.
Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: If your app has `15 activities` that means you need to use `fragments`. Use a single `Activity` and put a listener on the `Activity` and use that listener on your `fragments`.

Comment: I have fragments in most of activities, I would want sone other solution.

Comment: Then use a `broadcast receiver`.

Comment: You can move the common code to a base activity and make all your 15 activities extend it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BaseActivity As abstract and check the the internet as per the network changes.

- **Require permissions**

```xml
<!--Manifest.xml-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

- **NetworkChangeListener.java**

```java
/* Interface required to call in each activity with whom you extends BaseActivity.java */
public interface NetworkChangeListener {
    void networkAvailable();

    void networkUnavailable();
}
```

- **BaseActivity.java**

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NetworkChangeListener {

    private BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            /* previous way of doing it*/
            NetworkInfo ni = null;
            if (manager != null) {
                ni = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            }
            if (ni != null && ni.isConnected()) {
                networkAvailable();
            } else {
                networkUnavailable();
            }
        }
    };

    /*
     * If you like to check it manually you also cam use the bellow function for it
     * */

    public void checkInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        /* previous way of doing it*/
        NetworkInfo ni = null;
        if (manager != null) {
            ni = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        }
        if (ni != null && ni.isConnected())
            networkAvailable();
        else
            networkUnavailable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("NETWORK_STATE", "networkStateReceiver registerReceiver");
        registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("NETWORK_STATE", "networkStateReceiver unregisterReceiver");
        unregisterReceiver(networkStateReceiver);
    }
}
```

if you like to check the Internet manually you can use

```java
    /*
     * If you like to check it manually you also cam use the bellow function for it
     * */
    public void checkInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        /* previous way of doing it*/
        NetworkInfo ni = null;
        if (manager != null) {
            ni = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        }
        if (ni != null && ni.isConnected())
            networkAvailable();
        else
            networkUnavailable();
    }
```

- **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    /*
     * Check the log for the proper results
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void networkAvailable() {
        Log.e("NETWORK_STATE", "Connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void networkUnavailable() {
        Log.e("NETWORK_STATE", "Not Connected");
    }
}
```

Also if anything missed please refer [Github repo](https://github.com/BagwanAkib/NetworkApplication)

Comment: Thanks for complete code. I would be able to use my code to detect for internet in this. Connectivity manager doesn't tell whether Internet is available or not through the connected device.

Comment: @saksham you can please visit https://github.com/BagwanAkib/NetworkApplication  for more help i updated the use case as per your comment. as you required single object that will help to manage state change hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

Of course on Java you can't extends two classes, so you can create a new class BaseAcivity that extends class Activity and make the job done on the NetworkConnected on this class (BaseActivity), and extend it on your activities instead of class Activity.

Comment: I got your answer but I am a bit confused. Won't extending the same class multiple times cause it to instantiate multiple times. I only want one instance of my network listener running at a time as it would cause unnecessary network usage. Thanks